# How to fix server can't access $_POST data send by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I sent data to the server using Jquery AJAX but can't access them as `$_POST` variable. What am i doing wrong?
The PHP return returns error that the `$_POST['name'] is undefined`!

JS CODE

````
$(document).ready(function() {

    function load_friend_request() {

        $.ajax({
        url: "/friend_requests_main_loader.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: 'Kay'},
        success: function(html) { 
            //$("#friend_request:last-child").empty();
            $("#friend_request").append(html);
        }
        })
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        load_friend_request();
}, 2000);


});
</script>```

PHP CODE
`
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>`
````

Comment: Show php code too.

Comment: What shows `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: I have found a solution, i think ordering of the Jquery object matters...

Comment: check what headers it send ... if it's regular POST or maybe with JSON headers. you can use the option : dataType to set it. if it's JSON wo you need to fetch the data from php://input tlike that json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function load_friend_request() {

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/query_loader.php",
        data: { friend_count: 'count'},
        success: function(html) { 
            $(".friend-count").remove();
            $(html).insertAfter("#friend_request_mobile");
            $(html).insertAfter("#friend_request");
        }
        })
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        load_friend_request();
}, 2000);


});
</script>
```

The order at which type, post and url objects come is very important. I don't know if am right.